# Oracle PL/SQL invalid identifierCompilation failed

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

So am trying to create this trigger but i keep on having  this error

```
create or replace trigger Maxseats
Before 
insert or update or delete on BOOKING
for each row 
Declare
v_totalseats number (10);
v_count Number;
BEGIN
select count(*) into v_count from BOOKING where FLIGHTID=:new.FLIGHTID;

select TotalNoOfSeats into v_totalseats from FLIGHT where FLIGHID=:new.FLIGHTID;

IF
v_count > v_totalseats
then 
Raise_application_ERROR(-203, 'overbooked');
END IF;
END;​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I keep on getting is error

```
Error at line 14: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ""
```

Comment: You have one or more non-printing characters embedded in your code. A decent programmer's editor should help you here (or maybe even Word, as you don't have any quotes for it to mess up). Once you've sorted that out you can address the logic problems which @belayer mentions.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I attempted to compile, but there is nothing to be seen. I've encountered that before and normally somehow an unprintable character has gotten into he code and cannot be seen. If you have a hex editor that may help identify it.  Finding these can be extremely difficult; since it's short you can just try rewriting it. There are, however, couple of other issues.

A row level trigger cannot select from the table that caused it to fire. Doing so results in an "ORA-04091: *table* is mutating, trigger/function may not see it" This is a design issue. The rule, at least in my opinion, needs be enforced in the application layer not a DB trigger.

The other issue is the error code used in Raise_Application_Error. Valid values must be in range -20000 to -20999.